# Why can I not ping my service? - WSDL

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I am trying to create a `SOAP` service with a `WSDL` using `Spring Boot`.  I have a ping service defined in my `xsd`.

```
...
<xs:element name="ping" type="tns:ping"/>
<xs:complexType name="ping">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>
...
```

When I grab the `WSDL` from the server, here is what I get for the ping service:

```
...
<xs:element name="ping" type="tns:ping"/>
<xs:complexType name="ping">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
...
<wsdl:message name="pingResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:pingResponse" name="pingResponse"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
...
<wsdl:operation name="ping">
<wsdl:output message="tns:pingResponse" name="pingResponse"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
...
```

My configuration in with annotations in the `java`:

```
@Endpoint
public class RmisEndpoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://schema.stuff.org/riskonnect-service/v1_0";

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "ping")
    @ResponsePayload
    public PingResponse ping() {
        PingResponse pingResponse = new PingResponse();
        return pingResponse;
    }
}
```

Here is the `xml` I am sending in the `SOAP` request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:v1="http://schema.stuff.org/riskonnect-service/v1_0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:ping/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am using `curl` to hit the service, with this command:

```
curl --header "content-type: text/xml" -d @request.xml http://localhost.org:8080/ws
```

I can get the `WSDL` back form the service, but I am not hitting my `ping` method.  What do I need to do?

Comment: What specifically happens when you run that curl command? Do you get an error? What does it say? What does the server receive? Does it log anything useful?

Comment: I get no endpoint `.ping` found.